# ¿Cómo debería ser mi modelo de base de datos?

Tags: base-de-datos

Cómo puedo hacer para que mis tablas me ayuden con la lógica de hacer amigos como Facebook.

La única condición es que el usuario confirma mi solicitud para ser amigos, asimismo, que la solicitud solo se envíe una vez.

Comment: Deja tu codigo PHP, para poder ayudarte

Comment: @Shareiv **¡La ortografía, la gramática y la puntuación son importantes! Recuerda, esta es la primera parte de tu pregunta que otros verán - ¿Acaso quieres dar una mal impresión?**  Antes de formulario una pregunta visita [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), asimismo, date [un recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que comprendas como funciona [SOes](http://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]podria ser asi :
asi podria ser tu modelo

Comment: ¿? o sea como..

Comment: subi una imagen ,espero te pueda aclarar algo

Comment: VOY A PROBARLO.